# Assign same BoxDecoration value to all Containers in the widget tree

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to have decoration (padding, margin, etc.) fields to be set to an application wide default value for all Container widgets?

I know we could create one instance of BoxDecoration, EdgeInstets, etc., store in a variable and assign only that variable in all Containers like this:

```
Container(
  margin: _margin,
  padding: _padding,
  decoration: _boxDecoration
)
```

But this is not what i mean. I mean even without assigning any value. I've tried to extend Container like
`class MyContainer extends Container { ... }` and set the desired default values in the constructor but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't extend the `Container`. You should extend the `StatelessWidget`. Flutter is more about composing than inheritance.

You should have something like this:

```
class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget{
  final EdgeInsets _globalPadding = EdgeInsets.all(4);
  final Widget child;

  MyContainer({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: _globalPadding,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Then you can use `MyContainer` in the place of any `Container`.

Comment: Thanks for this. But how do I get all the properties of `Container` inside `MyContainer`? Do I have to manually copy them all into my object in order to expose them? Say I wanted to expose `padding` on `MyContainer`. Do I now need to go in and manually add `padding` to my object? Seems an awful amount of effort where proper inheritance would expose them by default...